# How to add clarification to a duplicate question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

In the case where there is a duplicate question, but the poster of the duplicate question doesn't understand the answer, where can you put additional information to try and explain the answer?

Should I just extend the original answer, which is correct, but contains no explanation, or write an answer in the new question?

Comment: It's not my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, OP posed **the wrong question**.

Or at least, left out critical information, possibly due to a lack of research.

What you should do, depends on the duplicate-target:

1. If the targets answers are insufficient to the target question, add a good answer, like if you found the question any other way.

   That might also answer any question the OP has left.
2. Encourage OP to clarify his question, focusing on what he does not understand.

   That will lead to it (no longer) being a duplicate, at least of that question, thus becoming eligible for re-opening and answering (or closing for other reasons, like a different duplicate-target).

Comment: Thanks I've actually gone back and reread the question and determined it's not really a duplicate but a similar issue

Comment: In that case, number 2 is the only applicable part, though more with "does not apply because" instead of "don't understand this about the explanation".